# What is the most efficient way to update values of a table based on a mapping from another table

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update

I have a table including following details.

```
empID   department  location    segment 
1   23  55  12
2   23  11  12
3   25  11  39
```

I also have a mapping table like following

```
Field   old value   new value
Department  23  74
department  25  75
segment   10    24
location    11  22
```

So My task is to replace old values with new values. I can actually use a cursor and update departments first then segments so on and so forth . But that is time consuming and inefficient. I would like to know if there are any efficient way to do this. Which also need to support in future if we were plan to add more columns to the mapping.

cheers.

Comment: How many rows has your table?

Comment: 25000 rows give or take

Comment: Rething your design. Typical use case is to update the department from  23 to 74 **for empId = 1** (meaning the emp was moved).  You are doing a global renumberation of departments - is this a real intention?

Comment: Yes. This is a global transformation

Answer (score 2):

Check this if it solves the issue.

```
update emp set department = (select map.new_value from map where emp.department = map.old_value);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about copying the data to a new table?

```
CREATE TABLE newemp AS
SELECT e.empid,
       NVL(d.new_value, e.department) AS department,
       NVL(l.new_value, e.location)   AS location,
       NVL(s.new_value, e.segment)    AS segment
  FROM emp e
  LEFT JOIN map d ON d.field='DEPARTMENT' AND e.department = d.old_value
  LEFT JOIN map l ON l.field='LOCATION'   AND e.location   = d.old_value
  LEFT JOIN map s ON s.field='SEGMENT'    AND e.segment    = d.old_value
 ORDER BY e.empid;

EMPID   DEPARTMENT  LOCATION    SEGMENT
1   84  55  12 
2   84  11  12
3   75  11  39
```

You'll need obviously three passes through the mapping table, but only one pass through the emp table.

We use a LEFT JOIN because not all values will be changed. If no new_value is found, the NVL function uses the existing value of the emp table.

You could update the original table from this new table (if the new table has a primary key):

```
UPDATE (SELECT empid,
               e.department as old_department, 
               n.department as new_department, 
               e.location   as old_location,
               n.location   as new_location,
               e.segment    as old_segment,
               n.segment    as new_segment
          FROM emp  e
          JOIN newemp n USING (empid))
  SET old_department = new_department,
      old_location   = new_location,
      old_segment    = new_segment
WHERE old_department != new_department
   OR old_location   != new_location
   OR old_segment    != new_segment;
```

Comment: Interesting. I would try this out. But this won't work if i want to update the existing table. i guess.

Comment: To not update records which are not changed - `WHERE d.new_value IS NOT NULL OR l.new_value IS NOT NULL OR s.new_value IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I've added an update statement, which might still work with 25k rows.

Comment: I can't find a way to do it in one step without a helper table. The mapping table might contain duplicate values,so we run into 
ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Comment: Thanks i will try this out. I could make a twist for this and include into my scripts.